# Get error "ReferenceError: event is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, keypress

On project exists next js-function

```
function LoginKeyPressCheck() {
$('#txtusername, #txtpassword').keypress(function (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode; // here get error
    $('#Errormsg').html('');
    $('#Err_ValidateUser').html('');
    if (charCode === 13) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#Err_ValidateUser').html('');
        if ($.trim($('#txtusername').val()).length === 0) {
            $('#Err_ValidateUser').html('Validation Error: Value is required');
        }
        else {
            loginProcess();
        }
    }
});
```

When click button `TAB` get error "ReferenceError: event is not defined".

Try to debug this function in FireBug but from line `var charCode = (evt.which)...` cursor moves in `else` block.

I can't get where is problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
```

variable **event** was not defined, so you can not use it

Comment: OMG.. why i didn't see this. Thanks.

Comment: You are a genius ;) (y)

Answer (score 2):

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
```

this should be

```
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
```

You use event.keyCode, but never define it, it's just a typo in your code